# deprecated Spring AnnotationConfiguration

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans

I have the following java code:

```js
package modelo.util;

import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    
    static {
        try {
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log the exception. 
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
    
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Does the following line deprecate the above code:

```
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
...= new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

I am working with `hibernate 4.3.1` and `Netbeans`. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The javadoc says:

> All functionality has been moved to [Configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html)

Just replace `org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration` with `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration`.

`Configuration.buildSessionFactory` has been deprecated in favour of the method that takes a `ServiceRegistry`. You'll have to configure one with a `ServiceRegistryBuilder`.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
builder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = builder.build();
sessionFactory = configuration.configure().buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

Comment: look this pic, sorry i havent privilegies for edit my last comment
https://s24.postimg.org/wzuf43kxx/2222.png

Comment: > hello again,
> Im following this guide : 
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zb2cW25prCQ
> I modifed how you recommed but when i run the proyect appears this:
> https://s27.postimg.org/4vo8kthhf/2222.png